# PowerBuilder function Pos, Mid does not work after migration

Tags: powerbuilder

I have migrated a Powerbuilder 9 application to PowerBuilder 12.5. After the migration, some functions are not working.

Following code is from a function which has blob argument blobi.

```
long ll_position, ll_start, ll_end

ll_position=Pos(String(blobi),'~f@1~r~n',1) //does not work.
```

The above line won't work in new version. I tried to check what value i get from ll_position:

```
messagebox("ll_position: ", ll_position)

In PB 9, it returns 1
In PB 12.5 it returns 0
```

Next step:

```
ll_start=ll_position+5 

ll_end=Pos(String(blobi),Char(126),ll_start)  //does not work.
```

I get following return values:

```
messagebox("ll_end: ", ll_end)

In PB 9, it returns 10
In PB 12.5 it returns 0
```

Next step:

```
dw_test.Object.numb[1]=Long(Mid(String(blobi),ll_start,ll_end -ll_start)) //does not work.
```

I get following return values:

```
long abc 
abc = dw_test.Object.numb[1]

messagebox("dw value is: ", abc)

in PB 9 it returns an integer like 1234
in PB 12.5 it returns 0
```

Please help me regarding what is problem with the above functions and how can I change them to work with PowerBuilder 12.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerBuilder 12.5 uses Unicode strings by default, so your String() function is taking two bytes to create one character. To maintain your existing functionality, use

```
String (blobi, EncodingANSI!)
```

Good luck,

Terry